# You know when you've been on StackOverflow too much when

Tags: discussion, off-topic, fun

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [You know you've been browsing Stack Overflow too much when?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11115/you-know-youve-been-browsing-stack-overflow-too-much-when)

Well, the title says it all really.

Comment: The duplicate target of this question no longer exists. Should this question be reopened?

Answer (score 33):

You're participating in meta.stackoverflow.com :P

Comment: Definitely a good indicator.

Answer (score 22):

You know that this question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247342/you-know-youve-been-browsing-stack-overflow-too-much-when).

Comment: Or that you know a question is duplicated across more than one SO site and then migrate and merge the two questions!

Comment: Which is now a dead link :(

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 9):

You're starting to hate your own issue-management/bug-tracking system for not having voting and comment capabilities.

Answer (score 8):

You wish that the Cornify button was a permanent fixture of the website.

What? Don't look at me like that. You know damn well you pressed it hundreds of times too.

Comment: Oh jeah... the famous Cornify thread...

Comment: Yeah, but I only pressed it in the hopes of getting a badge! =P

Comment: +1 They should definitely bring it back!!!!  (Can you hear me Jeff?)

Answer (score 7):

You talk to someone at your university and chat about StackOverflow and when you tell him your username he goes, "Oh! You're the pony guy!"

Comment: Well, if you can't be famous for programming... :P

Answer (score 6):

You think of creating a legitimate question, which is also boring and has no chance of being answered!!!!

...just so that you can earn your **Tumbleweed** badge!!

Comment: Ask legitimate obscure questions on SO, like me...

Answer (score 4):

You shout "Downvote!" to the interns attempting to explain polymorphism.
You place a golden-star sticker on favorites items throughout the house.
You take your laptop to the restroom...
You use "Skeet" as a verb meaning *to answer questions*: "Don't mind me, I'm skeeting on SO."

Comment: 'Skeeting' also means something else...I'm just saying.

Answer (score 4):

You're checking your SO reputation BEFORE your first cup of coffee. Or even BEFORE you get out of bed ;-) `<placeholder for the obligatory xkcd link "laptops are weird" ;-)>` (don't know the number by heart, and xkcd is websensed here :s)

Comment: omg, i've been really bad out the coffee 2nd with MSO lately...

Comment: You meant "Morning Routine" http://xkcd.com/490/ didn't you?

Comment: @Jakub: jep, that's the one :)

Answer (score 3):

you're listening to somebody at a party, you like what he/she says, and you think "+1".

Answer (score 3):

When your significant other not only knows that stackoverflow.com exists, but also the names "Jeff Atwood" and "Jon Skeet".

Answer (score 2):

When you're reading this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your reputation (not rep score) on TheDailyWTF.com is almost forgotten, yet your reputation on SO ends up being exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have 73,933+ reputation...I'm looking at you Jon Skeet.

Comment: I've got 99 problems but a Skeet ain't one of them.

Comment: I almost wish he would fly to the Boston Dev Days. I would love to meet the guy...

Comment: @Thomas: I suspect there are going to be a lot of disappointed people in London. I'm extremely ordinary in so many ways.

Comment: You realize how dated this answer is going to be in less than a week when you have to come back and change that to 83,933.

Comment: @MichaelPryor, Oh, it's actually *10 times* that amount already.

Answer (score 0):

You start dreaming about Stack Overflow and SOpedians.  Seriously.

A few night ago I had a dream that Jeff was hosting DevDays at his home, and 'we' (a bunch of SOpedians and I) were wandering around randomly.  I came accross Jeff's Lightsaber (ala Star Wars) on a mantel.  Being curious, I picked it up and was checking it out.  Jeff came in, saw me, and screamed ***"Don't touch the Lightsaber!  Get out, Stu!  Out!"***

Comment: Less cheese before bed in future...

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching the upvote/downvote button in a Lotus Notes Discussion Database :(

Answer (score 0):

You feel strangely jealous of Jon Skeet and his sky-high reputation, even though you've never met the man and he seems perfectly normal and nice.

Answer (score 0):

When you have to check your profile on one of the sites to confirm your own age...